# ggplot2: control panel placement in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I have a dataset with nested factors, similar to the `mpg` dataset which has `model` nested within `manufacturer`:

```
mpgsub <- subset(mpg, manufacturer %in% c("audi", "dodge","jeep","subaru"))
mpgsub$model <- as.factor(mpgsub$model)

table(mpgsub$manufacturer, mpgsub$model)
```

If I use `facet_grid` by `manufacterer` and `model`, I get empty panels:

```
ggplot(mpgsub, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(manufacturer~model)
```

[image]

I would like to make a ggplot that facets by model, but arranges the panels in rows by manufacturer.

I tried this in with `facet_wrap`.  I realize I have some control over the panel ordering if I change the order of the levels of the `model` factor, but it still just wraps without regard to `manufacturer`.

```
#order models by manufacturer
levels(mpgsub$model)
mpgsub$model <- factor(mpgsub$model, levels=c(
                "a4", "a4 quattro","a6 quattro" ,         #Audi
                "caravan 2wd", "dakota pickup 4wd", 
                "durango 4wd", "ram 1500 pickup 4wd",     #Dodge    
                "grand cherokee 4wd",                     #Jeep
                "forester awd","impreza awd"  ))         #Subaru

ggplot(mpgsub, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point()+  facet_wrap(~model, nrow=4, ncol=4)
```

[image]

Ideally, I would have the panels arranged in rows by manufacturer, even though this means different row lengths because in my subset each manufacturer has a different number of models.  I arranged the picture below in a graphics software- is there any way to make ggplot2 do this? 
[image]

I know I have some control of things like this with `scales=FREE` argument as discussed under the `# Free scales ----` [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html#examples), but it appears to only work on x or y axes, and I want to reserve the y-axis for a different variable.

Comment: This isn't something that faceting can easily do, in my experience. I would recommend splitting the data by manufacturer and then plotting each row separately. You will probably have to manually align the plots and set axis limits the same for all panels.

Comment: I'm messing around with this a little bit, but I think your best bet might be splitting the dataframe by manufacturer, making a list of `ggplot` objects, and plotting them how you want with `cowplot`. I could try to put together an answer with that if you think it could fit your situation. The advantage to `cowplot` is that it can align axes, similar to what facets do.

Comment: I've often had to resort to using the library `gridExtra` for this kind of thing. Check out baptiste's help page here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is enough to get you on the right track? Key contribution is the `ggarrange` method from the `ggpubr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

mpgsub <- subset(mpg, manufacturer %in% c("audi", "dodge","jeep","subaru"))
mpgsub$model <- as.factor(mpgsub$model)

mpgsub1 = mpgsub %>%
  filter(manufacturer == "audi")

mpgsub2 = mpgsub %>%
  filter(manufacturer == "dodge")

plot1 = ggplot(mpgsub1, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(~model) +
  labs(title = "audi")

plot2 = ggplot(mpgsub2, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(~model) +
  labs(title = "dodge")

plot3 = ggarrange(plot1,plot2, nrow = 2)

print(plot3)
```

[image]

Comment: Your plot is not properly arranged on the left